# Swagger data type number round issues

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, openapi

I have declared few properties as `type:number` in my app.yaml file. I am getting money values from backend as `String` that I am converting into `BigDecimal` as shown below:

`BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("24.00");`

It works fine within `Java` code, but when I check my service response, the output is auto rounded to `24`. Though, the auto round for zero makes sense, there is a requirement in this project to always display 2 digits after precision point, even for `0` it should display `0.00`.

I have verified with the junit cases, the `java` conversion of BigDecimal works fine. I suspect, there must be some configuration missing in `jackson`

I am using open API 3 and spring boot. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Why is that an issue anyway. If datatype is number then 2.110 is same as 2.11

Comment: Mathematically, there is no difference between 2.110 and 2.11. If you want the characters to be preserved you may transfer it as a string.

Comment: @henry/Vinay, I have updated question with more details of my problem.